# Accessing the controller in a Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller

I'm beginning to think that my Cocoa application is not really done according to the principles of MVC. My problem is the following:

I have some classes in my project, one of called `Copier.h` and another called `DropReciever.h`. `Copier` is sort of my main view controller, as it has all the bindings and main methods. `DropReciever` is a custom implementation of an `NSView` to allow the app to accept files via drag and drop.

Now, is there an easy way to send messages to `Copier` from `DropReceiver`? Right now, the two don't know each other, and I can't think of an elegant way to connect them, since since they are both kinda instantiated seperately. How can I make them see each other? Or, is there an elegant, Coca-ish way to do this better?

(If you want to look at my source code, it's [here](http://bitbucket.org/winsmith/copymeister/src/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually do it is to instantiate DropReceiver in the nib and then add an `IBOutlet DropReceiver *` to your Copier.h, then drag a connection from the Copier instance to your DropReceiver in the window

Comment: I see that this was voted as the "correct" answer, but it sounds like winsmith actually wants to send messages in the other direction - from the view to the controller. This means that the view would need a `Copier *` reference, and the connection would need to be made in reverse.

Comment: It would be fairly easy to reverse the connection, or, once the connection is made, to do some sort of delegate thing

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to expose a property of the drop receiver as a binding, and bind the copier to it (programmatically). Then, in the drop method, have the drop receiver set the dropped content as the value of this property (which you would name something like `droppedObject`).

When you set the property, the magic of Bindings will set the bound property of your copier. The copier can react appropriately there in its setter method.

Answer (score 2):

I would have a delegate property on the DropReceiver. Whatever is responsible for tying these things together would set the delegate. The delegate object can be an id, or you could create a protocol for it (both idioms are common in Cocoa). I do this all over the place. You get the separation you need, without having to work around the houses too much.

The only downside, if you don't set the delegate on initialisation, is that all your calls to it need to be protected by `if( delegate )` checks.

Comment: This approach is described in more detail, including handling of the responder chain, on Matt Gallagher's blog: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/07/better-integration-for-nsviewcontroller.html